# Preg_split an unique string row

Tags: php, split, explode

So I have somewhat of an tough thing going on, and I can't seem to figure out how to properly split up my string.

Here is the `var_dump($line)`:

```
Er.php:155:string 'TEST     Test    Test2  Director of Testing  +31-20-406-0000 +31-20-406-0001     testing@gmail.com    0000-10-27  2001-08-01  TestLocation    Amsterdam   AMSTERDAM   Amsterdam   100         Reputation Management       EMPL    EMEA        FHAMS   TEST3                2016-10-05 13:07:00 2019-03-26 10:01:00' (length=338)
```

So for the past 2 hours, I've been attempting to split these sections up and I can't get it to work:

`$arr = preg_split("/[\s\n]/", $line);` - I've tried everything, but the string is using tabs, but also some are dependant on 2+ spaces, while some shouldn't be broken up.

I've tried to split them up using a single space, but that doesn't work since `2016-10-05 13:07:00`, `Director of Testing` and `Reputation Management` are a single space and that needs to stay together.

Expected outcome:

```
Array:
[1] => TEST
[2] => Test
[3] => Test2
[4] => Director of Testing
[5] => +31-20-406-0000
[6] => +31-20-406-0001
[7] => testing@gmail.com
[8] => 0000-10-27
[9] => 2001-08-01
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213051/discussion-on-question-by-sle-preg-split-an-unique-string-row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for your date string first. The date regex isn't 100% (e.g. 2020-13-49 25:61:61 would be found) but there are other threads if you are looking for that (number range validation is long in regex). You also should look for phone numbers, defined by starting with a `+` and containing integers and hyphens after. If either of those cases are encountered we capture that value. Additionally if two consecutive whitespaces (`\s`) or a tab (`\t`) are encountered have it spilt on that.

```
$test = 'SIMONSH     Test   Test2  Director of GCL Operations  +31-20-406-0000 +31-20-406-0001     Test.me@group.com    0000-10-27  2001-08-01  ZH    Amsterdam   AMSTERDAM   Amsterdam   100         Reputation Management       EMPL    EMEA        FHAMS   MORTELLM                2016-10-05 13:07:00 2019-03-26 10:01:00';
$arr = preg_split('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\+[\d-]+)\h*|(?:\s{2,}|\t)/', $test, -1,  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY| PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($arr);
```

Roughly a date check: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`
Phone number check: `\+[\d-]+`
The `\h*` after those two strings are because we don't care about trailing whitespace on those.

Two consecutive spaces or a tab: `(?:\s{2,}|\t)`
The `?:` makes the `()` non capturing otherwise you end up with the whitespace that caused the split in the result as well.

Comment: You should have pinged me that you had posted an answer so I could upvote...